# How to configure vue-router in laravel 7?

Tags: vue.js

I'm building project on laravel seven, following this instruction

https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-vue-router-example-from-scratchexample.html

But when I try to run

```
npm run dev
```

There are error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.mjs 2139:18-26
Can't import the named export 'computed' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
```

And many other errors like this.
There are solution, which suggests adding this lines to mix file

```
                test: /\.mjs$/,
                include: /node_modules/,
                type: "javascript/auto"
```

But this caused another problem:

```
"export 'default' (imported as 'VueRouter') was not found in 'vue-router'
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss
```

And potential solution for this problem causes other problems.
Are the some example of laravel-vue routing that actually works, or step-by-step instruction for that?

Comment: did you ever resolve this? kindly share your solution if you dont mind

Comment: @Flexi
I installed Vue3 without laravel ui, seems like default router instructions now don't work with Vue 2.
I still don't know how I can install Vue3 using laravel ui